# Extract command from logcat Android-TV

Tags: android, adb, android-tv

I am trying to extract the command that is called when I click a particular button on Android TV, Eventually I want to add it to an app, but for now I am just looking to call it via ADB for testing.

```
10-14 10:18:16.654  5058  5058 D SourceElementCallback: onElementClick position:7
10-14 10:18:16.656  5058  5058 W ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.bindService:1611 android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService:698 org.droidtv.channels.sources.SourcesUtils.bindToLoggingService:743 org.droidtv.channels.sources.SourcesUtils.switchTo:327 org.droidtv.channels.sources.SourceElementCallback.onElementClick:82
10-14 10:18:16.658  5058  5058 D SourcesUtils: PASSTHROUGH sourceUri:content://android.media.tv/passthrough/com.mediatek.tvinput%2F.hdmi.HDMIInputService%2FHW5
10-14 10:18:16.660  3878  3972 D org.droidtv.candeebug.Gateway: Returning successfully for event: {"event-type":"unknown.28","boot-count":9,"standby-count":9,"kernel-time":4030979,"data":{"original-event-type":28,"InputName":"Computer","uiname":"HDMI 1","ver":1}}
10-14 10:18:16.661  3878  5242 D org.droidtv.candeebug.h.a: Updated total event size to: 6815
10-14 10:18:16.670  2325  5682 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://android.media.tv/passthrough/com.mediatek.tvinput/.hdmi.HDMIInputService/HW5 flg=0x10000000 cmp=org.droidtv.playtv/.PlayTvActivity (has extras)} from uid 1000
10-14 10:18:16.673  3540  3540 D PlayTvActivity: onNewIntent Action android.intent.action.VIEW data content://android.media.tv/passthrough/com.mediatek.tvinput%2F.hdmi.HDMIInputService%2FHW5
10-14 10:18:16.673  3540  3540 D PlayTvActivity: device ID =5
10-14 10:18:16.673  3540  3540 D PlayTvActivity: onNewIntent: ACTION_VIEW fav_list_id -1
10-14 10:18:16.685  3540  3540 D PlayTvActivity: onResume STATE_STARTED
10-14 10:18:16.686  3540  3540 D TvSessionManager: setStreamType value true
```

it looks like this is the action that is called? how would call that through ADB?

```
sourceUri:content://android.media.tv/passthrough/com.mediatek.tvinput%2F.hdmi.HDMIInputService%2FHW5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d content://android.media.tv/passthrough/com.mediatek.tvinput%2F.hdmi.HDMIInputService%2FHW5 -n org.droidtv.playtv/.PlayTvActivity -f 0x10000000
```

it works with the %2F :-)

Comment: you could format your answer to make it more readable. right now, the answer and sentence are all mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the activity manager `am` in the following way:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d content://android.media.tv/passthrough/com.mediatek.tvinput/.hdmi.HDMIInputService/HW5 -n org.droidtv.playtv/.PlayTvActivity -f 0x10000000
```

Considering that the intent contains extra (see `(has extras)`), then the command above might be extended a bit in order to add this additional information as well.

The tricky part is to understand the key name and type to pass to the activity manager (I'm referring to "device id" that seems the data provided as extras).

Supposing this is an int value then you have to append:

```
--ei device-id-key 5
```

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#IntentSpec)

Comment: Thank you, it's getting closer, it now returns with:

"Warning: Activity not started, intent has been delivered to currently running top-most instance."

Comment: this is because the activity is already loaded and the system simply took it to the foreground.